# Does this sequence of complex numbers converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to determine if the following recursive sequence of complex numbers converges.
$$z_0 = 0, \quad z_n = \frac{1}{2i + z_{n-1}}, \quad n \geq 1.$$
I started by expanding the sequence:
$$z_1 = \frac{1}{2i}, \quad z_2 = \frac{1}{2i + \frac{1}{2i}}, \quad z_3 = \frac{1}{2i + \frac{1}{2i + \frac{1}{2i}}}, \dots, $$
so this is a continued fraction. What strategies can I use to determine if a sequence of complex numbers converges or not?

Comment: You can use the standard continued fraction formulas to get $z_n=p_n/q_n$ where $p_n$ and $q_n$ satisfy simple recursions. You can solve those recursions and then see whether $p_n/q_n$ converges to a limit.

Comment: By what it looks like, it should converge as $z_{n - 1} < z_n$ and $2i + z_{n - 1} < 2i$. If it repeats infinitely, I would suggest it converges to $0$ as the numerator $<$ denominator

Comment: Show it's a contraction mapping (maybe on $|z|<1$)?

Comment: @Dstarred $>$ and $<$ don't mean anything for complex numbers.

Comment: @NinadMunshi oops, I meant their coefficients. For OP: Every iteration of the sequence yields a fraction just less than one in their coefficients.

Comment: It would add MSE relevance if you’d elaborate on  _Why_ you need to determine this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to actually compute the first few terms. Using $i^{-1}=-i$, we get that

$$\begin{cases}z_0 = 0 \\ z_1 = -\frac{1}{2}i \\ z_2 = -\frac{2}{3}i \\ z_3 = -\frac{3}{4}i \\ \cdots\end{cases}$$

so it is relatively straightforward to conjecture (and prove via induction, an exercise for OP) that

$$z_n = -\frac{n}{n+1}i$$